# Orchard CMS custom widget view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I'm writing module for Orchard CMS, and I need to display elements of my content type in widget.

**Drivers/FilesWidgetDriver.cs:**

```
public class FilesWidgetPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<FilesWidgetPart>
{
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;

    public FilesWidgetPartDriver(IFileService fileService)
    {
        _fileService = fileService;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(FilesWidgetPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_FilesWidget", () => shapeHelper.Parts_FilesWidget(
            Files: _fileService.GetFiles()
        ));
    }
}
```

**Models/FilesWidget.cs**

```
public class FilesWidgetPart : ContentPart
{
}
```

**Views/Parts/FilesWidget.cshtml**

```
@using ModuleName.Models
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@{
    var files = (IContentQuery<FilePart>)Model.Files;
}
<div>
@foreach (var file in files)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(file.FileName, "GetFile", "FileAdmin");
}
</div>
```

**Migrations.cs**

```
public int UpdateFrom1()
{
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("FilesWidget", type => type
       .WithPart("FilesWidgetPart")
       .WithPart("WidgetPart")
       .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget")
    );
    return 2;
}

public int UpdateFrom2()
{
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("FilesWidget", type => type
        .WithPart("CommonPart")
    );
return 3;
}
```

But when I add widget to page, it's empty. What's wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing placement.

Comment: thank you! but I've already solve this problem by writing dynamic shape :)